# How to create a static HTML site from a folder of JSONs?

Tags: html, ruby-on-rails, ruby, json, heroku

So currently I am working on an application that does regular backups for Slack conversations. I managed to find a way to generate JSONs from each conversation. Using Ruby library: https://github.com/dblock/slack-ruby-client

The application will be hosted on Heroku and using scheduler it will schedule backups frequently.

My goal is to transform these JSONs into an independent HTML pages(with their css) that I later can upload to each user Dropbox account so he/she can browse his backed up conversations from any browser locally and privte.

An example of JSONs structure is:

- [username]

  - channels

    - general.json
    - random.json
  - groups

    - [groupname].json
  - DMs

    - [username].json

So, the above structure will produce similar structure but instead of .json it will be .html, and it will have a "index.html" to browse.

After doing some research, I noticed that this thing can be done using static-site generators, but I am totally clueless about them. Is there a ruby static-site generator that could do the above task exactly? (It would be perfect if someone could guide me to a tutorial or example), or is this done using another solution?

Thank you,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to make a script that does this, its on [Github](https://github.com/Dorgam/slackup).